# Retrieve records from Mongodb Collections in last in first row format

Tags: python, mongodb

Is there any way to store a record in Mongodb in the order what we want as I want to retrieve the data LAST IN is updated in the FIRST ROW

I have written a service which displays all the records that are there in the collection whenever the user enters into the page. If user wants to modify any existing or enters a new one, it should be in the first row but for me, it is displayed in the last row.

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def pinsert():
   insert_list = request.get_json(silent=True)
   DateTime_1 = dt1.datetime.now()
   if insert_list is not None:
       try:
         for i in insert_list:
            dct = {}
              for val in i:
                if val != '_id':
                    dct[val] = i[val]
                    if val == 'PLANT':
                        plant.create_index([('PLANT',pymongo.DESCENDING)], 
                          unique=True)
                    if val == 'P_ID':
                        plant.create_index([('PLANT_ID', pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
                           # OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
            plant.insert(dct)
            plant.update({'_id': ObjectId(dct['_id'])}, {'$set': {"datetime": DateTime_1}})
            plant.find().sort({"datetime": 1})

            print('plant details=',dct)
       rslt = {'message': 'Data saved Successfully', 'success': 1}
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        rslt = {'message': 'Plant name or Plant ID already exists', 'success': 0}
else:
    rslt = {'message': 'Fields are empty', 'success': 0}
return jsonify({'result': rslt})
```

Actual:

```
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "BI", "PLANT" : "s1", "P_ID" : "1", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:16.848Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "HYD", "PLANT" : "s2", "P_ID" : "2", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:30.533Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "hyd", "PLANT" : "s3", "P_ID" : "3", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:35:17.335Z") }
```

Expected:

```
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "hyd", "PLANT" : "s3", "P_ID" : "3", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:35:17.335Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "HYD", "PLANT" : "s2", "P_ID" : "2", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:30.533Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "BI", "PLANT" : "s1", "P_ID" : "1", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:16.848Z") }
```

If 2 are modified the order should be:

```
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "HYD", "PLANT" : "s2", "P_ID" : "2", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:30.533Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "hyd", "PLANT" : "s3", "P_ID" : "3", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:35:17.335Z") }
{"PLANT_TYPE" : "BI", "PLANT" : "s1", "P_ID" : "1", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:16.848Z") }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get below result:

```
"PLANT_TYPE" : "hyd", "PLANT" : "s3", "P_ID" : "3", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:35:17.335Z") } {"PLANT_TYPE" : "HYD", "PLANT" : "s2", "P_ID" : "2", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:30.533Z") } {"PLANT_TYPE" : "BI", "PLANT" : "s1", "P_ID" : "1", "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-05T18:34:16.848Z") }
```

use:

```
db.t.find().sort({'_ID':-1})
```